# Detect the presence or absence of a string in a pattern with R

Tags: r, string, loops, dataframe

I'm beginner in R coding. I need a hand to find an elegant way to do this:

I've got the following dataframe :

```
> df = data.frame(pattern=c('a,b,c','b','c,b','c'), nb=c(150,100,30,10))
> df
  pattern  nb
1   a,b,c  150
2       b  100
3     c,b  30
4       c  10
```

According to the presence of string, I want a dataframe like that :

```
  pattern   nb    a    b     c
1   a,b,c   150   150  150   150
2       b   100   0    100   0
3     c,b   30    0    30    30
4       c   10    0    0     10
```

I find this solution :

```
df$a <- ifelse(grepl("a" , df$pattern), df$nb, 0)
df$b <- ifelse(grepl("b" , df$pattern), df$nb, 0)
df$c <- ifelse(grepl("c" , df$pattern), df$nb, 0)
```

But in my real case, I got a lot of different patterns. I'm sure there is a way with a loop or function.
Of course, I'm not asking for a ready-made solution. I'm just asking for an idea of how to do it.
Many thanks in advance.

Greetings from France

Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(nb2 = nb,
        pattern_split = strsplit(pattern, ",", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest(pattern_split) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = "pattern_split", values_from = "nb2", values_fill = list(nb2 = 0))

  pattern    nb     a     b     c
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a,b,c     150   150   150   150
2 b         100     0   100     0
3 c,b        30     0    30    30
4 c          10     0     0    10
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your very quick and effective answer. It works great. Have a nice day.

Comment: Small note: When I run tmfmnk's solution as is, I see an error ```Error in strsplit(pattern, ",", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument```, which can be resolved by having the input data.frame constructed with ```stringsAsFactors = FALSE```. The question code could be edited so ```df = data.frame(pattern=c('a,b,c','b','c,b','c'), nb=c(150,100,30,10), stringsAsFactors = F)```

Comment: Xilliam, Thanks for your comment. I saw you posted a solution with a loop, but I don't see it anymore.